# handling different states of a complex gui control

Tags: c++, gui

I need to handle different states of a complex GUI control (such as NORMAL, DRAGGING, MARKING, ...). I came upon this idea:

```
void dispatch(auto const i, auto&& ...f)
  noexcept(noexcept((f(), ...)))
{
  std::underlying_type<std::remove_const_t<decltype(i)>> j{};

  ((j++ == i ? (f(), 0) : 0), ...);
}
```

There would be an enum like this:

```
enum State
{
  NORMAL,
  DRAGGING,
  MARKING
};
```

and I would use `dispatch()` in event handlers like so:

```
dispatch(
  state_,
  []{},
  []{}
);
```

What do you think?

EDIT: This might help to prevent nested `switch`es, which I find very hard to track.

Comment: Here's a [better](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/dispatch.hpp) implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get it.
`j` is the same type as the underlying type of `i` but without the `const`, and you could have made that clearer by using an explicit template parameter so you could leave the `const` out of the deduced type.
But the only thing you do is increment it, and since it started at 0, `j++` just makes it `1`.  So why not just initialize it to 1 instead of incrementing zero?

This assumes that the type of enum used can be compared against an integer, so not the `class` style.

No wait a minute... you *post* increment `j`, which means it's `0` when you do the comparison.  But you don't use `j` again, so what was the point of updating it?

Ah, I see... it's looped via the pack expansion of the comma operator.
And you say `switch` is hard to follow????  You have three functions, and an index 0,1,2.  You're doing a convoluted way to just index the list.

Instead, initialize a local array of three elements using a pack expansion, then subscript that.

Comment: the mechanics of doing the dispatch was not so important to me, as the idea of `dispatch()` itself. The various states and how they interact can be convoluted also. So, if you have an alternative to gigantic switches, I'd like to know.

Comment: actually, it could be argued, that `dispatch()` should return a value, but that's just an implementation detail; I wanted to illustrate the general idea.

Comment: In my designs (long time ago), such _states_ are dynamically defined and handle any kind of modal or contextual behavior of the UI, not just universal things planned by the framework.  A whole bundle of callbacks (e.g. all the mouse-related functions) are defined together, and to go into such a state, this handler is added to the front of the handler list.  You don't have all the code for different states in one place like in the above design; they are truly independent and extensible.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example or something.

Comment: also, nothing prevents you from invoking `dispatch()` in different places.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the complex declaration of `j` by just post-decrementing `i`:

```
void dispatch(auto i, auto&& ...f) noexcept(noexcept((f(), ...)))
{
  ((!i-- ? (f(), 0) : 0), ...);
}
```

But as JDługosz already pointed out, this is a very convoluted way of dispatching. Also, the compiler is generating quite bad code, equivalent to:

```
if (i++ == j)
    f[0]();
if (i++ == j)
    f[1]();
...
```

Why not keep it simple?

```
std::array<std::function<void()>, 3> functions{
  []{...},
  []{...},
  []{...}
};

...

functions[state_](); // call the given function
```

Of course, you want to add some bounds checking there. Your version would also have benefited from a check that `i >= 0 && i < sizeof...(f)`.

Comment: very nice, but I may be unable to decrement `i`, as it may be an enum.

Comment: also my implementation is not the best, an indices-based implementation would be better, but it was just an illustration. Indices would do no math. Also, in a gui, efficiency does not matter that much.

Comment: also, I usually try to avoid `std::function`, if I can.

Comment: Re `std::function`:  I thought the use of `auto` rather than a `typename T...` explicit declaration meant there was only one type.  But I'm not familiar with the new syntax, being stuck on old compilers for "real work".  I suppose that's not the case, or you would not be able to pass different lambdas.  So, the array issue has the problem of getting a common type.  For this case, you can use the plain function pointer since it's a stateless lambda: `void(*)()`.

Comment: Ah yes, no `std::function` is needed in that case. Also, you can use a normal array instead of `std::array` I guess, which also helps it deduce the size automatically.

Comment: in my asm analysis, an [indices implementation](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/dispatch.hpp) trumps an array.

Comment: @user1095108 Did you provide it with a constant value for `i`? If so, the compiler will be able to optimize the parameter pack expansion away. However, if it doesn't know what value `i` has at compile-time, things are different.

Comment: yes, it works very well, but the state code still doesn't look pretty.